# string in response instead of a correct JSON format

Tags: json, response

How to tell my customer's provider to send the response in a valid format, or I misunderstood something?

The response I get is:

```
{
    "Code": "202",
    "Message": "BUIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxLUE",
    "Status": "SUCCESS",
    "Data": "{\"PRxxxxxxX\":\"2712.0000\",\"TRANSACTION_ID\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\",\"REMARKS\":\"SUCCESS\"}"
}
```

My problem is that, I can not map back the Data section this way, so I have to trim out values with an excel, which is not a good solution in long term (like =LEFT(D8,FIND("TRANSACTION_ID",D8,18)-4))

When I told him this he replied the following:
"we are serializing the object hence slash is added automatically (below is the screen shot)

```
apiResult.Data = JsonConvert.SerializedObject(
```

**The slash will not appear in the actual output"

Comment: What language are you using? And have you tried parsing the JSON?

Comment: i guess you are getting serialize object from API. instead of that ask him to send json object along with the response

Comment: @DaemonBeast : I'm using a no-code platform, where parsing the JSON is not supported as I  know.

Comment: Having characters escaped in json-strings is normal. For example, you can open your devtools and paste in `JSON.parse("{\"PRxxxxxxX\":\"2712.0000\",\"TRANSACTION_ID\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\",\"REMARKS\":\"SUCCESS\"}")` in the console and  it will work.

Comment: How exactly are you receiving the data?

Comment: So I have to predefine the mapping path, like $.Data.REMARKS in the nocode platform and trigger the API and it will automatically map back the value from the response to the db.

Comment: @ippi It's a no-code platform, so I can not use devtools unfortunately